# Statements within catch block is not executing

Tags: java, exception, catch-block

I wrote a piece of code to `catch` specific `exception` with help from [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.sql/SQLExceptiongetErrorCode.htm). It is like:

```
catch (SQLException sqle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
String sqlMessage = sqle.getMessage();
String sqlState = sqle.getSQLState();
int vendorCode = sqle.getErrorCode();
System.out.println("Exception occurred:");
System.out.println("Message: " + sqlMessage);
System.out.println("SQL state: " + sqlState);
System.out.println("Vendor code: " + vendorCode); 
}
```

But I am getting output as:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYSTEM.PK_USERID) violated

at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:125)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:305)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:272)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:623)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:181)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_for_rows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:543)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1028)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2888)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2960)
at accessdb.Dao.insertnewuser(Dao.java:32)
at Registration.doGet(Registration.java:47)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

if the error is :

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYSTEM.PK_USERID) violated

and I am getting output as

```
Exception occurred:
Message: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:XE
SQL state: null
Vendor code: 0
```

if the error is :

> Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor The Connection descriptor used by the client was: localhost:1521:XE.

Why is the difference in output happening for same piece of code?

**EDIT:**
Ok, so here is the `try` block for further clarification.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Authentication and Logging in The Registered User
    Getset g=new Getset();
    Dao dao=new Dao();
    String userid="";
    String fname="";
//  PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
    String loginemail=request.getParameter("loginemail");
    String loginpassword=request.getParameter("loginpassword");
    if(loginemail.equals("")||loginemail.equals(" ")||loginpassword.equals("")||loginpassword.equals(" "))
    {
        response.sendRedirect("WelcomePage.jsp");
    }
    else{
    g.setloginemail(loginemail);
    g.setloginpassword(loginpassword);
    try {
        ResultSet rs=dao.loginauthentication(g);
        while(rs.next())   //Fetching all emails and passwords from user table
        {
            String regemail=rs.getString("regemail");
            String regpassword=rs.getString("regpassword");
            System.out.println(""+regemail);
            if(loginemail.equals(regemail) && (loginpassword.equals(regpassword))==true)
            {   
                System.out.println("55555");
                ResultSet rs1=dao.getnameid(g);
                while(rs1.next())   //GET USERID and name FROM NEWUSER TO USE AS PRIMARY KEY
                {
                     userid=rs1.getString("USERID");
                     fname=rs1.getString("FNAME");
                //  System.out.println(""+userid);

                }

                HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                  session.setAttribute("USERID", userid);
                  session.setAttribute("FNAME", fname);
                response.sendRedirect("UserHome.jsp");
                return;
            }
        }  
        if(rs.next()==false){
            System.out.println("caught");
            response.sendRedirect("WelcomePage.jsp");
            return; 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you post `insertnewuser` method?

Comment: Actually it is part of a J2EE project.Everything is working fine, I can assure that. Just I want to print the error in the browser to a user if he inserts something wrong. that is why I am experimenting with catching specific exceptions.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: The question with question mark `Why is the difference in output happening for same piece of code?` :)

Comment: @JonLin, I am not sure, but I believe the question is basically asking why the output is different for the two `java.sql.SQLException` cases.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you getting that stack trace if you are catching the exception and not printing a stack trace?

Comment: Yes, that is also strange...!! I am not printing `stacktrace`. I guess it may be `tomcat` or `eclipse` problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not posted enough of your code to provide a definite answer, but this is what you'd call an "educated guess": the `try` of your `catch` clause does not enclose this line of code:

```
accessdb.Dao.insertnewuser(Dao.java:32)
```

With your new code, the following hypothesis is even more plausible: your `insertnewuser` method has its own `try-catch` block that looks like this:

```
try {
  ...prepare an insert statement...
  stmt.executeUpdate(...);
} catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

This **swallows** your exception and makes your method complete normally in spite of the exception. Solution: **remove the entire `try-catch` block from that method** and make the method declare `throws SQLException`.

Comment: 1. Now you have `try` with no `catch`. Confusing. 2. There is still no evidence in that code of calling `insertnewuser`.

Comment: got my error. The piece of code for `catch` block should be added to the class where the exception is occuring. I was catching from wrong class.Thanks.

Comment: No, Subir, that may not be the best recourse. Instead **delete the entire catch block** in `isnertnewuser` and let the exception bubble up!

Comment: Eclipse is not permitting to delete `catch` anyway. :)

Comment: Eclipse has nothing to do with it, Subir. It just tells you that you have unhandled checked exceptions. Just have your method declare `throws SQLException`, this is one of the two quick-fixes offered.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. Note that this answer is just a guess since you didn't post enough code.

On one hand, you get the desired output when an `SQLException` is thrown **when trying to connect to the DB server**. Probably, it means that you put your `catch` block in the chunk of code that manages the connection to your DB.

On the other hand, you get an undesired output when trying to `insertnewuser` and an `ORA-00001` error is raised by the DB, which in turn causes an `SQLException`. That means that the connection to the database has succeeded, but the insert operation has not.

Do you have two try-catch structures?

Answer (score 0):

Let me join the play "let's guess the code" too: you're using some persistence abstraction and not calling `flush()`/`ormFlush()`/`what have you` -> so there's no guarantee of immediate insert -> so the SQLException gets thrown whenever/wherever?

Comment: I can assure you insertion is happening right after a user registers. I am creating the exceptions willingly to catch the exceptions specifically.