# Multiple Statement in catch block

Tags: java, try-catch

I have very simple question. I am not using it but I have curiosity to know the answer. Can we execute multiple statements in catch block only if the exception get catched? I mean in my code below will both statement will get executed or not? Let me add some code snippet to make it clear..

I have found this link but not giving me the answer to my question.
[link Click Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.sql/SQLExceptiongetErrorCode.htm)

The above link I found in this question asked by someone but It has very blurry code so hard to understand.
[stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765185/statements-within-catch-block-is-not-executing)

```
try {
    int x = doXProcess();
    int y = doYProcess();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error related x: " x + e.printStackTrace());
    System.out.println("Error related y: " y + e.printStackTrace());
}
```

Thanks you for your help and time.

Comment: Use a debugger to see how it works ;-)

Comment: No I did not tried it. While working I came to this situation. I know how to handle it, but this one code is just curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common to see multiple statements in a `try` block.

If an exception occurs on the first line, the second line is not executed.  Execution stops on any line where an exception is thrown; no lines past that point in the block are executed -- execution proceeds directly to the catch block.

If an exception is thrown from the `catch` block, execution again stops at the line on which the exception occurred.  From there you go to a `finally` block, if one is defined.

Comment: So in this case when exception get cought the following statement get executed and then program will get stopped executing.  Catch block won'e even bother to execute next statement.
System.out.println("Error related x: " x + e.printStackTrace());

Comment: :--->Yes I got the answer. I have did the experiment on it and I found the answer, but currently stackoverflow is not letting me to post the answer. I will post it later. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You can definitely execute several lines in the block of code handling the exception.

However, please note that your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. N number of statement can be executable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all the statements in the catch block are executed when a exception is caught.